# FontAwesome in span:after

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm using FontAwesome in **span**:after. It working fine in chrome but not working in IE.

```
<label><span class="sptxt">Hello</span></label>

.sptxt:after{
font-family: FontAwesome;
content: "\ea28";
text-decoration: inherit;
position: absolute;
font-size: 80px;
color: inherit;
margin: 0px 0 0 4px;
z-index: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
.sptxt{visibility:hidden;}
```

In the above code, I want hide the text **"Hello"** in **span**. FontAwesome icon has to be displayed in span. I want to replace **"Hello"** word with FontAwesome icon. It works as expected in **Chrome** but not in **IE**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do with text-indent instead of visibility.

[jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/tg_alfa/Lf0aukde/1/)

```
.element {
    position: relative;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
}

.element:after{
    content: "\f000";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: inherit;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 9999px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `span` or `i` tag for fontawesome. But here you are using `span` to display the content **Hello** so you can use `i` tag for fontawesome.

```
<label><span class="sptxt"><i></i>Hello</span></label>
```